# Border around includegraphics

Tags: graphics

Seems like the problem of border around includegraphics has already been brought up. But none of the solutions worked for me.
Here's how my border looks like:
[image]
And here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
lsdfjgofgkogkof kgdpgokfdgkdfog pdkpgodkgpodkg pfgkdgkdpgkf dgod k fpgkfdgdpfgod fkgdfgpdokfgop dkgpodkgop dkg dpgdkf gdkpdkog\\
\fbox{\includegraphics[center,cfbox=blue 1pt 1pt,fbox,frame]{name.png}}\\
kfogkdfpogkdf kpfogkfdpogdkf opdfkgpofdkgpodf kpofdgkopfdkgpdfk gpdfokgodfpk gdfopkgpofdkgodpfk pdofgk dfpk dgpokfgdfopgkdpf kpofg podfkgd pfokpfdgkpodfg
\end{document}
```

I'd be even more grateful if you could add in the comment how to better center the image as well. The above is the closest I could get to centered image.

Comment: I don't know why but `center` produces a shorter frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this:

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,center,cfbox=blue 1pt 1pt,fbox,frame]{name.png}}
```

Put "width" as first option in your includegraphics.

Another idea is to change margins just for the image using package changepage, like this:

In preamble put:

`\usepackage{changepage}`

An then use it adjusting relative to previous margin:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\fbox{\includegraphics[center,cfbox=blue 1pt 1pt,fbox,frame]{name.png}}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Sustitute -1cm for the decrement of margin size you need.

Comment: But I don't want to make my image smaller. And even if I did, it still doesn't work: http://imgur.com/DYpu6F7.

Comment: Thank you. The second solution works. I'm marking the answer as accepted until there is a way to do it without hardcoded values. If there is none, it's a pity.